# Multidimensional array - handling SQL results

Tags: sql, multidimensional-array

Say I want to create a page for each company, which in turn will list each employee and each of the duties they perform.  I want (for Holiday Inn):-

Michelle Hopkins    …   Duty Manager / Accountant / Front Desk

Anthony Archer      …   Night porter / Room service

Hannah Newell       …   Reservations / Bar Service

*But the below outputs:-*

Michelle Hopkins    …   Reservations / Bar Service

Anthony Archer      …   Reservations / Bar Service

Hannah Newell       …   Reservations / Bar Service

---

What is the correct syntax for storing the 'employee_duties' array in the 'employee_person_duties' array so that it can be displayed as above?

And is it possible to do this using a single SQL SELECT statement?

---

**DATABASE LAYOUT**

**COMPANY**

company / company_id

Holiday Inn / 1

Travelodge / 2

Buena Vista / 3

---

**COMPANYPERSON**

companyid / personid / duty

1 / 14 / Duty Manager

1 / 14 / Accountant

1 / 14 / Front Desk

1 / 15 / Night porter

1 / 15 / Room service

1 / 16 / Reservations

1 / 16 / Bar service

---

**PERSON**

person_id / person_name

14 / Michelle Hopkins

15 / Anthony Archer

16 / Hannah Newell

**PHP**

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT person_id, person_name
       FROM companyperson
       INNER JOIN person
       ON personid = person_id
       WHERE companyid = '$company_id' ";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
     $employee_people[] = array('person_id' => $row['person_id'], 'person_name' => $row['person_name']);
}

foreach($employee_people as $employee_person)
{
     $person_id = $employee_person['person_id'];

     $sql = "SELECT duty
            FROM companyperson
            INNER JOIN person
            ON personid = person_id
            WHERE companyid = '$company_id'
            AND person_id = '$person_id' ";

     $employee_duties = array();

     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
     {
          $employee_duties[] = array('duty' => $row[duty']);
     }
     $employee_person_duties[] = array($employee_duties, 'person_name' => $employee_person['person_name'], 'person_id' => $employee_ person['person_last_name']);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<?php foreach ($employee_person_duties as $employee_person_duty): ?>
<a href = "/person/<?php htmlout($employee_person_duty ['person_url']); ?>">
<?php htmlout($employee_person_duty ['person_name']); ?></a>
.....
<?php $duties_array = array(); foreach ($employee_duties as $employee_duty)
{   
     $duties_array[] = htmlspecialchars($employee_duty ['duty'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}
echo implode(" / ", $duties_array); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**EDIT**

Ah, that is a very good solution, thanks.  However it doesn’t enable me to display that data in a form other than a concatenated string, i.e. I may need to display in a vertical list or in individual cells in a table, etc.

And I need to add another separate description field (that I'll need to have the option to format differently – see below) so I think I’m ultimately going to have to find out how to hold an array within an array so that I have individual control of each of the result elements.  Can anyone help?

**COMPANYPERSON**

companyid / personid / duty / dutydescription

1 / 14 / Duty Manager / Taking bookings; manning phones; general management

---

Michelle Hopkins

Duty Manager (*Taking bookings; manning phones; general management*)

Accountant  (*Balancing the books; company payroll*)

Front Desk (*Greeting guests; taking reservations*)

Comment: Answer is here: http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?1137572-Multidimensional-array-handling-SQL-results&p=5519307#post5519307 Credit to fretburner.

Answer (score 0):

**And is it possible to do this using a single SQL SELECT statement?**
Yes; assuming you are using my_SQL the first query would be the following:

```
SELECT person_id, person_name, Group_concat(duty SEPARATOR '/') as duty
       FROM companyperson
       INNER JOIN person
       ON personid = person_id
       WHERE companyid = '$company_id'
       GROUP BY Person_Id, Person_Name
```

The SQL returned would already have the rows grouped by user with a / separating duties.

GROUP CONCAT SYNTAX: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: Thanks xQbert.  But (re. my edit) in the long run I'm going to need to find out how to store/display an array within an array.